# Cant create a connection due to duplicate values

Tags: powerbi

I have a problem, where I can't create a connection between two columns of two tables. It says one of the columns should have unique values. It should, I made sure I queried distinct values. I trimmed the data, I also changed everything to lowercase. I even went ahead and used remove duplicates in PowerQuery (when I selected all the columns and even on the single column).
The problem still exists and I can't create a connection.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Have you tried with other columns?, probably is a formatting problem. Check the format of the column, and try to do a simpler example first to make it work. If not , try to post screenshot or something to give more context please =)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but it was a single row with no value. I don't know how pbi thought it wasn't unique, but removing that value solved it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm ashamed to say this, but I spent 6 hours on this today. And then I realised the message might just be wrong and there is something else going on. There was a row where the value was null, so "". That caused the problem. And it wasn't even duplicated. And removing the blanks in PowerQuery didn't work either.

So I removed the "" directly in the query and now everything works as it should.